# Когда появилось обращение "госпожа"?

Tags: этимология

Могли ли в дохристианской Руси к молодой княгине Ольге обратиться "госпожа"?

Comment: Нацкорпусом РЯ появление этого слова относится примерно к 1725 году. Возможно, что ранее в хождении было слово «господыня», т. е. владелица.